# kafka-manager process getting automatically killed?

Tags: apache-kafka, yahoo-kafka-manager

I am using kafka-manager version 1.1 to monitor kafka, and kafka  version is  2.11-1.1.0. And zk version is 3.4.10.

zookeeper is working fine. But sometimes kafka brokers gets automatically killed, and it thorows only a single message on terminal "killed" and gets stopped the same is happening for kafka manager too.

I have 64GB RAM and when I checked RAM usage then I found that only 1GB RAM is being used by all the processes and still I have 63GB RAM. So I think memory is not an issue here. But I did not find the reason why it is stopping processes.

Please suggest me what I need to change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Edit the process to write out to a log file. Enable TRACE or DEBUG logging on it